# Xcode facebook login error CLOSED

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

Hi I was reading and reading tutorials here on http://developers.facebook.com/ .

About Login in to Facebook and publish Feed from application, my problem is I cannot login to Facebook at all.

And I can't get it work. It sucks, annoying, and there is no clear tutorial/explanation about this.

Im trying to login from my app, when safari open and then the URL were like going nuts
blinking..

And I dont get an error, why?

Is there any CLEAR tutorial About Loging in?

it works GREAT on simulator, but not on the Device.

Im on Xcode 4.5 beta right now, but it also doesn't work on 4.4.

I need Help!

**[CLOSED]**

**EDIT**: I fixed it! I was so stupid... I was struggling in seven days just to login to FB,
then i changed ( **Cookies Allowed on the device** ), Everything worked PERFECT!

Damn that device just needed some cookies.. Lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated to the recent FB sdk about 2 weeks ago. Here's the way I've done it:

```
//FB recommends to put these two in the app delegate in their sample apps but you can place them other places
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog((@"session.state is %d",session.state));
                                         if(session.state==513){
                                             [AppPrefererences sharedAppPrefererences].faceBookLoggedIn=YES;
                                             NSLog((@"facebookLogin pref has been set to yes from inside appDelegate"));
                                         }
                                         else{
                                             [AppPrefererences sharedAppPrefererences].faceBookLoggedIn=NO;
                                         }
                                     }];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // FBSample logic
    // We need to handle URLs by passing them to FBSession in order for SSO authentication
    // to work.
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}


    //Then whereever you want to initiate the log in (i use mine in a tableView)
      AppDelegate  *appDelegate =(AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

 if (![appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]) {
                    [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
                    facebookLoginLabel.text=@"Facebook Log Out";
                    [AppPrefererences sharedAppPrefererences].faceBookEnabled=YES;
                }
                else{
                    facebookLoginLabel.text=@"Facebook Log In";
                    [AppPrefererences sharedAppPrefererences].faceBookLoggedIn=NO;
                    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];                    
                }
```

And then whererever you want to post you do this:

```
  [FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:@"any thing you want to post"
                                    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){}];
```

And, also don't forget to set the FBLoginViewDelegate

Let me know if you have any questions! Hope it helps!

Comment: What are the AppPreferences ?

Comment: Oh my bad that's just my custom class I use to implement nsuserdefaults. Just ignore that part of it