# authentication using facebook id, facebook sdk, ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

After doing authentication using facebook by doing

```
FBSessionLoginBehavior behavior =   FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView;
appDelegate.session             =   [[FBSession alloc] init];

[appDelegate.session  openWithBehavior:behavior 
                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"session is %d",session.state);
                         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


                     }
 ];
```

I am always getting

```
session is 513
```

**Question :**

```
what is the meaning of 513
```

Please assist me about this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Facebook SDK error codes](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes) tell me that it's "User cannot poke via API". It seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432983/xcode-facebook-login-error-closed) handling 513 error explicitly. Also have a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353476/post-image-on-facbook-wall-and-facebook-friends-wall).

Answer (score 2):

The FBSession.state = 513 is the FBSessionStateOpen.
I could not find any document explaining this, the possible session states are: (found it in the iOS FacebookSDK)

```
FBSessionStateCreated                   = 0,
FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded        = 1,
FBSessionStateCreatedOpening            = 2,
FBSessionStateOpen                      = 1 | FB_SESSIONSTATEOPENBIT,
FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended         = 2 | FB_SESSIONSTATEOPENBIT,
FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed         = 1 | FB_SESSIONSTATETERMINALBIT, // NSError obj 
FBSessionStateClosed                    = 2 | FB_SESSIONSTATETERMINALBIT, // "
```

The numbers are wrong, but the states are right. Try to "po session.state" and you will se the  enum value.